# Monad transformer for signaling no solution list with `Nothing`

Tags: haskell

Greetings fellow Haskellers.

This is a toy version of a larger constraint satisfaction problem I am
working on at the moment.

The code below employs the list monad transformer to represent a given
positive integer `n` as a sum of small even integers in different
ways.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.List
import Control.Monad

sumToN' :: Int -> ListT Maybe [Int]
sumToN' n
  | n == 0 = pure []
  | otherwise = 
      do
        x <- ListT $ Just [1..4]
        guard $ x <= n
        guard $ even x
        fmap (x:) $ sumToN' $ n - x
```

After loaded into GHCi the function works sort of as expected.

```
λ> sumToN' 8
ListT (Just [[2,2,2,2],[2,2,4],[2,4,2],[4,2,2],[4,4]])
λ> sumToN' 7
ListT (Just [])
```

However, I was hoping to add some style to my code by defining a
function that would return `ListT Nothing` in case no solution is
found. This is not what I got. The result I got is likely to be a
result of how `mzero` is defined for `ListT`.

```
λ> mzero :: ListT Maybe [Int]
ListT (Just [])
```

My question is: **Is it possible to use monad transformers to combine
lists and `Maybe` so that `Nothing` would signal no solution in the
code.** (I am not looking for a hack. I want to know if monad
transformers would somehow support this directly.)

As background information, the following code does not use monad
transformers at all and achieves the same result as above in terms of
indicating no solution by `[]`.

```
sumToN :: Int -> [[Int]]
sumToN 0 = [[]]
sumToN n = do
  x <- [1..4]
  guard $ x <= n
  guard $ even x
  map (x:) $ sumToN $ n - x
```

This gives us basically the same result as list transformer.

```
λ> sumToN 8
[[2,2,2,2],[2,2,4],[2,4,2],[4,2,2],[4,4]]
λ> sumToN 7
[]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `Int -> [[Int]]` version? It's perfectly reasonable for a given input to return an empty list of 0 solutions without needing to bother with additional layers of `Maybe` and `ListT` to signal no solution.

Comment: It would be perfectly possible, but I agree with @chepner that the transformer is overkill here. A list without the `Maybe` would be perfectly idiomatic, I should think.

Comment: Nothing wrong per se. However, what is wrong with trying to understand how monad transformers could be used to combine these two abstractions (list and `Maybe`) to provide desired behaviour? Don't we want to understand how these creatures behave?

Comment: IIRC, `ListT` is broken anyway.

Comment: @jhu Everything you can do with `MaybeT` you can do it as well with a proper `ListT` implementation (the one from "transformers" is bugged, use 
 an alternative like http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t). Experiments that put `ExceptT`, `StateT` and `WriterT` above/below `ListT` can be more instructive.

Answer (score 1):

While I think simply cutting out the `Maybe` is the idiomatic solution, here is the answer to the question you're asking. Since we know the exact nature of your monad transformer stack, we can just introspect on its values using pattern matching.

```
testList :: ListT Maybe a -> ListT Maybe a
testList (ListT (Just [])) = ListT Nothing
testList x = x
```

If you want something that talks to the type system a bit more, you could construct a monad instance out of [`NonEmpty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) (bear in mind, this will be no more of a well-behaved monad transformer than `ListT` is, but it will do what you want it to). We could call it `NonEmptyT`.

```
newtype NonEmptyT m a = NonEmptyT { unNonEmptyT :: m (NonEmpty a) }

-- Instance implementations omitted for brevity

instance Functor m => Functor (NonEmptyT m) where
    ...

instance Applicative m => Applicative (NonEmptyT m) where
    ...

instance Monad m => Monad (NonEmptyT m) where
    ...

instance MonadTrans NonEmptyT where
    ...
```

Now we can write

```
testList' :: [a] -> NonEmptyT Maybe a
testList' [] = NonEmptyT Nothing
testList' (x:xs) = NonEmptyT $ Just (x :| xs)
```

This takes an ordinary list and turns it into a `NonEmptyT Maybe`. What makes this different from your previous approach is that the value you don't like (`ListT (Just [])`) is *not even meaningful* in our new type. You can have `NonEmptyT Nothing` and you can have `NonEmptyT (Just someNonemptyList)`, but the expression `NonEmptyT (Just [])` will not even typecheck.

This isn't quite the behavior you're looking for, with the transformer actually interacting with and understanding the layer below it, but I think it's a step in the right direction, since it outright forbids programmers from constructing the value you don't want to exist.

[Full working example](https://gist.github.com/Mercerenies/7aad5e60e81dd97e3c0a0cfc1fc03702).

---

(Footnote: Unfortunately, GHC didn't want to let me use either `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` or `DeriveFunctor` on this new type, so you do actually have to write the instances by hand. If anyone knows why these extensions fail in this case, I'd love to know the reason.)

Comment: This would be the "hack" solution I referred to above.

Comment: @jhu Alright, I think I understand now. I don't think the thing you're looking for is, in general, possible. But see my edit; it may be a step in the right direction, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: I believe `testList'` should be possible to generalize to `MonadPlus m => NonEmptyT m a`. Am I right?

Comment: I want to add that you should never use list transformer from `transformers` library because this data type is broken. Better use something like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-transformer

Comment: Ok, I will give a proper implementation of list transformer a try at some point. (Somewhat weird if the version from `transformers` is buggy. Maybe a licence issue.) I will do that before I select the answer above to be correct. Thanks!